# Why do some vsts work in Bespoke Synth (or any DAW) and others don't?

Tags: vst, synth

I use a lot of the vst synth plug ins from K Brown. They all work in Bitwig and Waveform but only some of them work in Bespoke Synth. I have been googling why some vsts work and others don't but I can't find anything that comes anywhere near addressing that question. They all seem to be made the same way and are all vsts, do I can't think of why some would work and some not.

I also am just starting to program my own audio plugs and I plan on making some virtual instruments and I think this information will help me. I'm not asking for a too in-depth answer, just a short explanation that will point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Because the VST protocol has never been 100% stable.

Answer (score 1):

Might simply be a 32 bit / 64 bit problem.

Bitwig still supports 32 bit plugins while most host softwares have stopped to do so. (You can use something like JBridge to still use them in such a host.)
So check if the problematic VST are 32 Bit while the working ones are in 64 Bit.